# Can`t fix: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solc, compilation, mocha

I´m doing my first smart contract, these errors are probably no npm but versioning problems. Though intensive research I could not find a proper way to fix it. Thank you for your help!

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { interface, bytecode} = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async() => {
    //get a list of all accounts
   accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();    
          
    //Use one of those accounts to deploy
    //the contract
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Salve!'] })
        .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'})

});

describe('Inbox', () => {
    it('deploys a contract', () => {
        console.log(inbox);

    });
});
```

This is the compile.js

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Inbox.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, "utf8");

module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Inbox']

;
```

And the package.json

```
{
  "name": "inbox",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.1.3",
    "solc": "^0.8.9",
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

The inbox.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;
    
    function Inbox(string inititialMessage) public {
        message = inititialMessage;
    }
    
    function setMessage (string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you show your smart contract code too ?

Comment: Sure!
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;
    
    function Inbox(string inititialMessage) public {
        message = inititialMessage;
    }
    
    function setMessage (string newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
        
    }
    
}

Comment: The solc version is your dependencies should match the version used in the contract.

Answer (score 1):

In the test is for a call function. Does not need a transaction. In your example you did a transaction.

Your answer has worked, but the test to a call function returns Assertion_Err.

Do this:

1. Try set the variable *message* with some text in your .sol contract. Like this:

```
string public message = "my first hello!";
```

2. In your Inbox.test.js - try change the it() test like this:

```js
  it('has a default message', async () => {
        const message = await inbox.methods
                                .message()
                                .call();
        assert.equal(message,'my first hello!');
```

Look now, the message == 'my first hello!' and pass the test, without any payable function only a call().

I can't figured out why the deploy (this code below) didn't modifies  the contract when it was allocated on the blockchain.

```js
inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
        .deploy( { data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hello'], })
        .send( { from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seems to answer the question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I had the similar problem when was testing my contract on mocha and I did not solution for my problem. I just suggested some changes in the tests.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/66883)

Answer (score 0):

First you will have an issue as your solc version is ^0.8.9 while your smart contract pragma is ^0.4.7.

So you should change your contract pragma to ^0.8.9 to be compatible with your solc version.

---

Your smart contract needs to be slightly modified for v0.8.9:

*I changed your function name from Inbox to myInbox to avoid conflict with the contract name. And I added the memory/storage keyword now required for strings*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Inbox {
    string public message;

    function myInbox(string memory inititialMessage) public {
        message = inititialMessage;
    }

    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
```

---

Compiling your contract with solc v0.8.9 is different as what you did as per the current [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc):

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const solc = require("solc");

const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Inbox.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath, "utf8");

let input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    [inboxPath]: {
      content: source,
    },
  },

  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

module.exports = {
  abi: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]["Inbox"].abi,
  bytecode: output.contracts[[inboxPath]]["Inbox"].evm.bytecode.object,
};
```

---

And finally your test file is almost unchanged (except for interface becoming abi, and I added a test to call the setMessage function) :

```
const assert = require("assert");
const ganache = require("ganache-cli");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());
const { abi, bytecode } = require("../compile");

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  //get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(abi)
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ["Salve!"] })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
});

describe("Inbox", () => {
  it("deploys a contract", () => {
    console.log(inbox);
  });

  it("sets the contract message", async () => {
    await inbox.methods
      .setMessage("test message")
      .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: "1000000" });
  });
});
```

And the tests are passing.

Anyway, you'd usually use a framework taking care of all of that such as truffle or any other. While it can be instructive, it's certainly not something worth your time to redo all the time.